# Addition of OrderBy clause to a DocumentDB LINQ query breaks it (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using the Azure Documents SDK in C# in .net core 1.0.1 with LINQ to abstract a simple Fetch method that takes lambdas as parameters.  It works fine EXCEPT when I add an `ORDER BY` clause – although I have no idea why.  Here’s the method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Fetch<R>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T, R>> orderby, int count)
{
    var results = new List<T>();
    var collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_config.Database, _collectionId);

    // This works
    //var document = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(collectionLink).Where(predicate).Take(count).AsDocumentQuery();

    // This ** DOESN'T ** work
    var document = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(collectionLink).Where(predicate).OrderBy(orderby).Take(count).AsDocumentQuery();

    var feedResponse = await document.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
    results.AddRange(feedResponse.AsEnumerable<T>());
    return results;
}
```

With the addition of the `.OrderBy()` method, I get 0 results returned.  With its removal, I get the expected 10 (albeit in insertion order).  In looking at the SQL being generated by the `.AsDocumentQuery()` method, I can’t see anything obviously wrong, so I’m at a bit of a loss as to why. 
For completeness, here’s an example of its’ usage...

```
var result = data.Fetch(f => f.Firstname.Contains("i"), x => x.Firstname, 10);
```

... and the query that it produces:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM root WHERE CONTAINS(root["Firstname"], "i") ORDER BY root["Firstname"] ASC
```

Is this an SDK bug or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I see strange behavior like this it's usually because you have a hash index (the default) as opposed to a range index on that field. Check the indexing policy for the collection.

Comment: That sounded plausible, so I re-created my collection (via the SDK) with an `IndexingDirective` of `Exclude` - but I'm still seeing the same result (or rather lack of them!)  :-(

Comment: You can't exclude it. You have to change it from default of hash to range.

Comment: You're right on both counts - Thank you! For everyone else's benefit, I'll paraphrase below.

A hashed index allows for mapped queries like `KEY = VALUE` to be efficient (its basically a distributed hashtable).
A ranged index allows for ambiguous queries, like `KEY > VALUE, KEY < VALUE, VALUE < KEY < VALUE` etc...

If you simply exclude indexing (either wholesale at collection level or at document/property level), DocumentDB will error when attempting a filtered (ranged) query - Ie. the `.OrderBy()` clause in my original post.